# Is there a way to make a Point feature show as text?

Tags: javascript, gis, openlayers-3

In Leaflet there is an option for icons to be div's instead of images.  Which meant you could make a marker which is just text, essentially a label which could be moved by the user.  Which is what I am trying to reproduce using OL3 with no success.

Is there anything available in OL3 to have text on the map which behaves like a Point feature?  As in, can be moved in edit mode and attached to the map in a vector layer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible if you set correctly the style for markers (without using an image):

```
new ol.style.Style({
    text: new ol.style.Text({......
```

Look at the following working example: 
http://jsfiddle.net/pfavero/yabta24t/13/

Answer (score 0):

I think [Overlay](http://openlayers.org/en/master/apidoc/ol.Overlay.html) is what you need: see http://openlayers.org/en/master/examples/overlay.html